# PHPUnit, fill an input that is not contained in a form

Tags: input, phpunit

My question is really simple,

I work on a site where to access login form, user need to fill a first email input, then click on a 'next' button and then access the 'real' login form.

I try to build a unit test with PHPUnit but i dont find the method to fill this input while it's not contain in a form.

```
$mail = self::randomMail(10, "@yop.com");
$input = $crawler->filter('input#emailValue')->first();
$input-> ???;

$link = $crawler->filter('div#btn-next')->first()->link();
$crawler = $client->click($link);
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly but I think whether you use $_POST or $_GET you can simulate form data with filling $_POST or $_GET.

Comment: There is no query launch after filling this input, only a javascript verification (when clicking the btn-next button) that allow or not the 'real' form to appear (with a fadeIn)